# How to make two dependent drop down using ajax response and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I kindly need help on dependent drop down list in zend framework for php. I go through many answers but my problem still persists.

I want to create two dropdown on the basis of ajax response. On the basis on 1st dropdown selection second dropdown will populate.

my ajax response is like

```
{"val1":"text1","val2":"text1","text3":{"subval1":"subtext1","subval2":"subtext2","subval3":"subtext3"},"text4":{newsubval1:newsubtext1,newsubval2:newsubtext2},"others":"Others"}
```

i want if i select text1 2nd dropdown remains hidden, and if i select text3 then only 3 option will display in 2nd dropdown.

i tried it like

```
                        res = JSON.parse(res);
                        $el = $(".first-dropdown");
                        $subel = $(".second-dropdown");
                        $el.empty();
                        $subel.empty();
                        $el.append($("<option></option>")
                                    .attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
                        $.each(res, function(value, key) {
                                if(key instanceof Object || key instanceof Array) {
                                    $el.append($("<option></option>")
                                            .attr("value", value).text(value));
                                    $.each(key, function(value1, key1) {
                                    $subel.append($("<option></option>")
                                            .attr("value", value1).text(key1));
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    $el.append($("<option></option>")
                                            .attr("value", value).text(key));
                                }
                            });
```

my html code is like

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 first" id="first">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 control-label">first request*</label>
            <select class="first-dropdown" style="width: 300px;">
                <option >--Select Reason--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 second hidden" id="explaination">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 control-label">Second Request*</label>
            <select class="second-dropdown" style="width: 300px;">
                <option >--Explain Reason--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

but it shows all values in 2nd dropdown . I want only values of selected option in second dropdown.

Comment: if you only want values set in second dropdown why does response contain anything else?

Comment: @charlietfl: i want values in both dropdown. if first dropdown contains more level values then only second dropdown populate.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand that logic. Normally the change event of the first would make request for data for the second. If you need to send 2 sets, send them in separate arrays within the main object. Your big object doesn't look very code friendly ... `first:[{"value:1,"text:"xxx"}, {"value:2,"text:"yyy"}], "second":[{"value:100,"text:"xxx"}, {"value:200,"text:"yyy"}]`

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle, it will help understand what you trying to do.

Comment: @charlietfl: on the basis of ajax response i'm creating first dropdown . if option contains multiple values like in above option 3rd then the values will be shown in 2nd dropdown . my question is , how can i relate these values ?

Comment: Not clear enough what the relationships are to help

Comment: my question is can i change nested dropdown into two separate dropdown  ?if yes then how?

Comment: You need a far better outline of what these relationships are to get any further along here. It is just not clear enough for anyone to follow right now